# finalData is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to learn redux by creating multi step form (reactjs), everything is going fine, except when i click a button then all the data should go to one variable `finalData`, but its not going and i'm getting:

`TypeError: finalData.map is not a function`

When i check `console.log(userData);` i get all the data, but i want data to go to `finalData`, and `changeFinalData` is the one which updates it.

When i console log finalData i get: `finalData => [...finalData, userData]`.

What am i doing wrong?

my code:

```js
    import React, { useContext } from "react";
    import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
    import "antd/dist/antd.css";
    // import { multiStepContext } from "../StepContext";
    //-------------
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import {
      changeName,
      changeUserId,
      selectId,
      selectName,
      changeSetStep,
      changeUserData,
      changeFinalData,
      selectCurrentStep,
      selectUserData,
      selectFinalData,
    } from "../features/app/appSlice";

    function ThirdStep() {
      // const { setStep, userData, setUserData, submitData } =
      //   useContext(multiStepContext);

      //----
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const userData = useSelector(selectUserData);
      const finalDataa = useSelector(selectFinalData);
      console.log(userData);

      const submitData = () => {
        dispatch(changeFinalData((finalDataa) => [...finalDataa, userData]));

        changeUserData("");
        changeSetStep(1);
      };

      return (
        <Form>
          <Form.Item
            label="City"
            name="City"
            initialValue={userData["city"] || ""}
            onChange={(e) =>
              dispatch(changeUserData({ ...userData, city: e.target.value }))
            }
          >
            <Input type="string" />
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            label="Landmark"
            name="Landmark"
            initialValue={userData["landmark"] || ""}
            onChange={(e) =>
              dispatch(changeUserData({ ...userData, landmark: e.target.value }))
            }
          >
            <Input type="string" />
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            label="Postal Code"
            name="Postal Code"
            initialValue={userData["postcode"] || ""}
            onChange={(e) =>
              dispatch(changeUserData({ ...userData, postcode: e.target.value }))
            }
          >
            <Input type="string" />
          </Form.Item>

          <div>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={() => dispatch(changeSetStep(2))}
              color="secondary"
            >
              Back
            </Button>
            <span> </span>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={() => submitData()}
              color="primary"
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      );
    }

    export default ThirdStep;
```

my appSlice.js:

```js
    import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

    export const appSlice = createSlice({
      name: "app",
      initialState: {
        userData: [],
        finalData: [],
        currentStep: 1,
      
      },
      reducers: {
        changeSetStep: (state, action) => {
          state.currentStep = action.payload;
        },
        changeUserData: (state, action) => {
          state.userData = action.payload;
        },
        changeFinalData: (state, action) => {
          state.finalData = action.payload;
        },

       
      },
    });
    export const {
      
      changeSetStep,
      changeUserData,
      changeFinalData,
    } = appSlice.actions;

    export const selectCurrentStep = (state) => state.app.currentStep;
    export const selectUserData = (state) => state.app.userData;
    export const selectFinalData = (state) => state.app.finalData;

    export default appSlice.reducer;
```

DisplayData.js:

```
    import React, { useContext } from "react";

    import {
      TableContainer,
      TableHead,
      TableBody,
      TableCell,
      TableRow,
      Table,
    } from "@material-ui/core";
    import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { selectFinalData } from "../features/app/appSlice";
    // import { multiStepContext } from "../StepContext";

    function DisplayData() {
      // const { finalData } = useContext(multiStepContext);
      const finalDataa = useSelector(selectFinalData);
      console.log(finalDataa);
      return (
        <div>
          <TableContainer style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Table
              border="1"
              style={{ width: "70%", justifyContent: "center" }}
              size="small"
              aria-label="caption table"
            >
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "burlywood", color: "aliceblue" }}
                >
                  <TableCell>First Name </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Last Name </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Contact Number </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Email Address </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Country </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>District </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>City </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Landmark </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Postal Code </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {finalDataa.map((data) => (
                  <TableRow key={data.email}>
                    <TableCell>{data.firstName} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{data.lastName} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{data.contact} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{data.email} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{data.country} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{data.district} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{data.city} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{data.landmark} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{data.postcode} </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default DisplayData;
```

my App.js:

```js
    import { useState } from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import Header from "./components/Header";

    import FirstStep from "./components/FirstStep";
    import SecondStep from "./components/SecondStep";
    import ThirdStep from "./components/ThirdStep";
    import { Stepper, StepLabel, Step } from "@material-ui/core";
    // import { multiStepContext } from "./StepContext";
    import { useContext } from "react";
    import DisplayData from "./components/DisplayData";
    //---

    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import {
      changeName,
      changeUserId,
      selectId,
      selectName,
      changeSetStep,
      changeUserData,
      changeFinalData,
      selectCurrentStep,
      selectUserData,
      selectFinalData,
    } from "./features/app/appSlice";
    //--

    function App() {
      const SelectFinalData = useSelector(selectFinalData);
      const SelectCurrentStep = useSelector(selectCurrentStep);

      // const [name,setName]=useState('kalle')

      // const { currentStep, finalData } = useContext(multiStepContext);
      const showStep = (step) => {
        switch (step) {
          case 1:
            return <FirstStep />;
          case 2:
            return <SecondStep />;

          case 3:
            return <ThirdStep />;
        }
      };
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <h3 style={{ color: "red", textDecoration: "underline" }}>
              Reactjs multi step Application
            </h3>
            <div className="center-stepper">
              <Stepper
                style={{ width: "18%" }}
                activeStep={SelectCurrentStep - 1}
                orientation="horizontal"
              >
                <Step>
                  <StepLabel></StepLabel>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                  <StepLabel></StepLabel>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                  <StepLabel></StepLabel>
                </Step>
              </Stepper>
            </div>
            {showStep(SelectCurrentStep)}
            {SelectFinalData.length > 0 ? <DisplayData /> : ""}
          </header>{" "}
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: in reducer: changeFinalData: (state, action) => { state.finalData = action.payload; }, and initial state of finalData is : finalData: [], and export : export const selectFinalData = (state) => state.app.finalData;

Comment: It's a bit hard to track your code since it's incomplete. Can you update your question to include full complete component and reducer/slice code?

Comment: @DrewReese can you now help ? as you can see i'm trying to print everything in DisplayData.js with finalDataa.map

Comment: @DrewReese and my index.js is simple : import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./app/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are trying to implement your reducer logic in your UI code. You are storing a function in state, not actually updating state values.

```
dispatch(changeFinalData((finalDataa) => [...finalDataa, userData]));
```

This just stores the function `(finalDataa) => [...finalDataa, userData]` into state in the `state.app.finalData` state.

## Solution

While you *could* just invoke the action payload function in your reducer and pass it the current `finalData` state

```
changeFinalData: (state, action) => {
  state.finalData = action.payload(state.finalData);
},
```

This is not how you'd want to maintain your state. You will instead want to pass in the action payload the data you want to update your state with.

```
changeFinalData: (state, action) => {
  state.finalData.push(action.payload);
},
```

And dispatch the action with the data payload.

```
dispatch(changeFinalData(userData));
```

Since you use similar logic in all your other reducer cases you will want to implement similar updates. This is so the reducer function maintains control over how state is updated.

Comment: Perfect answer !, one thing, when i refresh the page data disappears, shouldnt it be saved in state ?

Comment: @waleedd32 No, react state resides in memory only. If you want to persist it you'll probably want to persist your redux store to localStorage and when your app loads initialize your store from localStorage. This is something you can handle manually or there are libraries out there to help with this.

Comment: one last question related to this question. In my appSlice.js i have userData set as an array 'userData: []' , but in my ThirdStep.js component i am dispatching an object to that userData 'dispatch(changeUserData({ ...userData, city: e.target.value }))', my question is why am i not getting any errors ? is dispatch converting it to an array then updating ?

Comment: in hooks for example const [userData, setUserData]=useState([]); use state would return an array, so is dispatch doing same thing ?

Comment: @waleedd32 You are mutating the shape (from array to object) with `dispatch(changeUserData({ ...userData, city: e.target.value }))`. You likely don't see the issue since objects are associate arrays of key-value pairs and `userData["city"]` is valid syntax for either accessing an array element by index or accessing an object property. And no, `dispatch` isn't like `useState`.

Comment: could you help with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249117/saving-input-data-to-different-keys