# saving input data to different keys

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm new to Redux work, trying to learn by doing. Here I have AntD input, when user writes something then it saves it to the object keys `billingName:` and `billingContactPerson`, but I have also two buttons `sender` and `receiver`, when user clicks `sender` button then it takes data from `redux` and put it to `input`, but my question is how to save that data to the same `billingName` and `billingContactPerson`. I have tried to save it in `useEffect` `billingName = PickUpName`, but it did not save it.

My code:

```js
  let billingName: any;
  let billingContactPerson: any;
   
  const userData = useSelector(selectUserData);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const DeliveryName = userData.deliveryName;
  const PickUpName = userData.pickUpName;
  const DeliveryContactPerson = userData.deliveryContactPerson;
  const PickUpContactPerson = userData.pickUpContactPerson;


  const [name, setName] = useState(billingName);
  const [contactPerson, setContactPerson] = useState(
  billingContactPerson 
 );
  const [payer, setPayer] = useState("");

   useEffect(() => {
   const names = () => {
  if (payer === "receiver") {
    billingName = DeliveryName;
    dispatch(changeUserData({ ...userData, billingName }));
  }
  if (payer === "sender") {
    billingName = PickUpName;

    dispatch(changeUserData({ ...userData, billingName }));
  } else {
    return billingName;
  }
};
setName(names);

const contactPersons = () => {
  if (payer === "receiver") {
    billingContactPerson = DeliveryContactPerson;
    dispatch(changeUserData({ ...userData, billingContactPerson }));
  }
  if (payer === "sender") {
    billingContactPerson = PickUpContactPerson;
    dispatch(changeUserData({ ...userData, billingContactPerson }));
  } else {
    return billingContactPerson;
  }
};
setContactPerson(contactPersons);

   
  }, [payer]);

  const senderPays = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPayer("sender");
  };

  const receiverPays = (e: any) => {
   e.preventDefault();

   setPayer("receiver");
};

<div>
          <Button onClick={senderPays}>sender</Button>
          <Button onClick={receiverPays}>receiver</Button>

<Form.Item
          label={t("o.billingName")}
          name="billingName"
          initialValue={userData["billingName"] || name || ""}
        >
          <Input
            onChange={(e: any) =>
              dispatch(
                changeUserData({ ...userData, billingName: e.target.value })
              )
            }
            type="string"
          />
        </Form.Item>

       <Form.Item
      label={t("orders.ContactPerson")}
      name="billingContactPerson"
     
      initialValue={
        userData["billingContactPerson"] ||
        contactPerson ||
        ""
      }
    >
      <Input
        onChange={(e: any) =>
          dispatch(
            changeUserData({
              ...userData,
              billingContactPerson: e.target.value,
            })
          )
        }
        type="string"
      />
    </Form.Item>
</div>
```

Comment: it is only adding 'billingContactPerson'

Answer (score 0):

If you're new I recommend you to start with `reduxjs/toolkit`. It is the new recommended way of writting redux logic.

[Let's Learn modern redux](https://www.learnwithjason.dev/let-s-learn-modern-redux)

About the question you asked. You can try triggering an function after the redux logic or after sending the data to the input field and give type to `billingName` and `billingContactPerson`. So, that you can more catch errors.